# Colouring of a pie chart

Tags: qgis, google-maps, color, chart, color-ramp

How can I automatically insert different colors for different attributes in creating pie chart in QGIS. I have multiple attributes and coloring them differently takes alot of time. Is there way that I can select them all and differently colored at the same time.